# How to determine the .csv file having header or not, thru java?

Tags: java, spring

I have requirement, where I have to upload the different types .csv files and extracting the data.
My code should be generic, to read the different .csv files. Before reading the file, make sure that the file have header or not, if not I should reject the file. So how can I verify whether the file having header or not ?

Comment: Can you show your work before asking for help. What have you done so far?

Comment: You can find from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7122040/8110565) , may it help you

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you can't.

If you know what you expect in header, you can validate that first row of csv contains what you expect it to contain.